# Excel Sum-If with Criteria for a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am looking to determine the number of my employees that have been employed with my company for several increments of time each year. The time periodes are

Less then 6 monthes
Between 6 and 12 monthes
Between 12 and 24 monthes
Between 24 and 36 monthes

Inorder to caculate this I need to create additional helper columns for each year and all these categories. These are the columns D to AO in the Employee Data Sheet.

I then calculate the totals in my Totals Page

I would like my Totals Page to do the same calculations without using the helper columns D to A0 in my Employee Data Sheet and having to create any more helper columns. I also do not want to create any additional helper columns in my Totals Page either. I want to be able to easily create new columns dynamically when I need to add new years in my Totals Page. I do not need to display specific information about individual employees as I am just looking at totals

I am assuming that I would need to have SumIf statements with critera as the range inorder to do these calculations

Here are images and of my spreadsheet and the formulas that I am using

Employee Data Page

[CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lypY8.png)

```
 D5 Formula: =IFERROR(IF(AND(VALUE("12/31/"&D$1)>=VALUE($B5),VALUE("12/31/"&D$1)<=VALUE($C5)),1,""),"")      

 E5 Formula: =IF(D5<>"",VALUE("12/31/"&D$1)-$B5,"")

 G5 Formula: =IF(AND(E5>=365.25/2,E5<365.25),1,"")

 H5 Formula: =IF(AND(E5>=365.25,E5<365.25*2),1,"")

 I5 Formula: =IF(AND(E5>=365.25*2,E5<365.25*3),1,"")
```

Totals Page

[CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5R0r.png)

```
 B3 Formula: =SUM(DSPStats[0-6 2017])
 B4 Formula: =SUM(DSPStats[6-12 2017])
 B5 Formula: =SUM(DSPStats[12-24 2017])
 B6 Formule: =SUM(DSPStats[24-36 2017])
```

Here is a copy of my spreadsheet

[VIEW HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yY5qBVXypHV2QDPBLkpqWE4WpNtZK1Re/edit?pli=1#gid=1219117670)

I explained this in the details section

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.